# Cannot execute PDO using binary parameters with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a model that uses a closure table to construct a nested hierarchy. My entities all use binary optimised UUIDs as their primary keys with the uuids being stored in a `BINARY(16)` column.

To insert a node in the closure table I execute the function below, here `$tenantUuid`, `$ancestorUuid` and `$descendantUuid` are all binary values.

```php
    public function insertNode($tenantUuid, $ancestorUuid, $descendantUuid)
    {
        $table = $this->table;

        $query = "
            INSERT INTO {$table} (tenant_uuid, ancestor, descendant, depth)
            SELECT :tenantUuid1, tbl.ancestor, :descendantUuid1, tbl.depth+1
            FROM {$table} AS tbl
            WHERE tbl.descendant = :ancestorUuid1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT :tenantUuid2, :descendantUuid2, :descendantUuid3, 0
        ";


        DB::connection($this->getConnectionName())->statement($query, [
            'tenantUuid1' => $tenantUuid,
            'tenantUuid2' => $tenantUuid,
            'descendantUuid1' => $descendantUuid,
            'descendantUuid2' => $descendantUuid,
            'descendantUuid3' => $descendantUuid,
            'ancestorUuid1' => $ancestorUuid
        ]);
    }
```

However when this query executes I get the following error:

```
(PDOException(code: HY000): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\\xEA\\x04\\x18VWG...' for column '?' at row 1
```

The looks like the binary values are getting converted to strings and escaped.

How do I modify this function to correctly insert the raw binary values?

I am also open to alternative methods of running this query without using PDO's as none of the data I am inserting is user generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting binary directly into the query string results in the binary literals being interpreted as multibyte string characters and therefore causes invalid string syntax when interpreted by MySQL.

Similarly using a PDO would result in the casting of the binary literals to a string which is then automatically escaped. The escaped string is then too long to be inserted into a BINARY(16) column.

The answer is to convert the binary literals to hexadecimal values which can be easily inserted into the query string using the [hexadecimal literal notation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) x'value'. The resulting function is shown below.

```
public function insertNode($tenantUuid, $ancestorUuid, $descendantUuid)
{
    $table = $this->table;

    // Convert to hex for use in the query string (binary breaks the query)
    $tenantUuid = bin2hex($tenantUuid);
    $ancestorUuid = bin2hex($ancestorUuid);
    $descendantUuid = bin2hex($descendantUuid);

    $query = "
        INSERT INTO {$table} (tenant_uuid, ancestor, descendant, depth)
        SELECT x'{$tenantUuid}', tbl.ancestor, x'{$descendantUuid}', tbl.depth+1
        FROM {$table} AS tbl
        WHERE tbl.descendant = x'{$ancestorUuid}'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT x'{$tenantUuid}', x'{$descendantUuid}', x'{$descendantUuid}', 0
    ";

     DB::connection($this->getConnectionName())->statement($query);
}
```